# Limit $a_{n+1}=\frac{(a_n)^2}{6}(n+5)\int_{0}^{3/n}{e^{-2x^2}} \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to find the limit when $n$ goes to $\infty$ of

$$a_{n+1}=\frac{(a_n)^2}{6}(n+5)\int_{0}^{3/n}{e^{-2x^2}} \mathrm{d}x, \quad a_{1}=\frac{1}{4}$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks to me that the integral tends to a finite value, while the $n + 5$ factor increases, so you get something that grows quite fast.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: @vonbrand The integral tends to $0$. It is indeed finite, but actually $n+5$ times the integral is bounded.

Comment: Sorry, misread the upper index. Too little coffee...

Comment: @vonbrand The upper bound is indeed not so far from being $3n$ modulo a character...

Answer (score 3):

First show by induction that
$$
0<a_n\leq \frac{1}{4}
$$
for all $n$.

Then use that to show that $a_n$ is decreasing.

Since it is also bounded below, $a_n$ converges to $a\in[0,1/4]$.

Now 
$$
\int_0^{3/n}e^{-2x^2}dx\sim \frac{3}{n}.
$$

So, passing to the limit in the induction formula, we get
$$
a=\frac{a^2}{2}.
$$

So the only possibility is $a=0$.

Hence
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} a_n=0.
$$

Let me know if you want me to expand some points.

Comment: Hey! thank you very much, it was very clear. I have only one doubt, How do i get that $$\int_0^{3/n}e^{-2x^2}dx\sim \frac{3}{n}.$$??

Answer (score 3):

Obviously $a_n > 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Since
$$
    \int_0^{3/n} \exp(-2 x^2) \mathrm{d}x  < \int_0^{3/n} \mathrm{d}x = \frac{3}{n}
$$
We have
$$
    a_{n+1} < \frac{1}{2} a_n^2 \left(1 + \frac{5}{n} \right) \leqslant  3 a_n^2
$$
Consider sequence $b_n$, such that $b_1 = a_1$ and $b_{n+1} = 3 b_n^2$, then $a_n \leqslant b_n$ by induction on $n$. But $b_n$ admits a closed form solution:
$$
      b_n = \frac{1}{3} \left(\frac{3}{4} \right)^{2^{n-1}}
$$
and $\lim_{n \to \infty }b_n = 0$. Thus, since $0 < a_n \leqslant b_n$,  $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$ by squeeze theorem.

Comment: Nice approach, I don't even know why I made it more complicated, +1.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: apply the mean value theorem on the integral.